# Temperature around 0°C

Tags: expressions

How to say that the lowest temperature will be around 0°C (e.g. -1°C ~ 1°C)?

My attempt is:

> 最低气温会成0°C左右。

Comment: You almost got it right! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As fefe has mentioned, you could use “**在**”…左右 /上下/ 附近 to describe a range near some position, somewhat like describing locations.

> 最低氣溫**在** 0 度**左右**；
>   蛋白質凝固的溫度**在** 65 度**上下**。

It is not needed for exact values.

> 現在室溫 7 度；
>   冷凍室的溫度是 -20 度。

For estimated values, you may also use 約 (about) to indicate uncertainty.

> 最低溫**約**為零度。

It is worth noting that Celsius is omitted in all examples above, since Celsius is usually the only tempreture scale employed. Other scales, such as Fahrenheit and Kelvin, only exist in special contexts like academic research. You may use …°C (pronounced “度 C”) or 攝氏…度 if explicitness is needed.

Here is an example video for daily usages. In this weather forecast ([YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPKU9ErxMCA&hd=1#t=1m25s)) of Next TV, Taiwan, the reporter uses

> 白天最高溫**降到**只有 24 度**左右**。

to express the tempreture **lowers to** tempretures **near** 24°C.

**Sidenote:**
Please note that she also uses

> 最低溫**下探** 17 度。

to indicate the lowest temperature would **touch a lower bound** of 17°C. This is mainly used in Taiwan for weather and stock reports. It is not used in China and usually would be interpreted as **lower by 17 degrees** rather than **lower to 17°C**.

Comment: I've never heard "下探" used in this way.

Comment: I usually hear it in news reports like this [weather report](http://tw.news.yahoo.com/強烈冷氣團來襲-低溫下探10度-110148242.html) and this [report about oil price](http://www.lrn.cn/media/hotspot/201112/t20111206_1040539.htm).

Comment: Notice that the weather report is from Taiwan, where different expression maybe used from Beijing. I'm not familiar with expressions used in Taiwan, but I doubt it should mean the temperature "lowered by" 10 degrees instead of "lowered to" 10 degrees. As for the report about oil price, I still fill it wired. "下探" can be used for prices for oil, stock market, etc, but usually without a number.

Comment: Thanks, fefe. I check that with my friend from Beijing and you're right. I'll correct it.

Comment: +1 This is the type of answers I want to see! Nice, elaborated answers! :D

Answer (score 4):

There is only one defect in your attempt, we would say:

> 最低气温会 **在** 0°C左右。

Comment: One thing: in Chinese, do you read the "C" part?

Comment: Usually, it is just read as "度". The full name is "摄氏度". "°F" is read as "华氏度".

Comment: To expand on what @fefe said: if you are specifying the number as well, you generally place it before the 度.  In this example, 0°C would typically be read as 摄氏零度.

Comment: @Claw I have no problem with "零摄氏度". In fact I always place the number before "摄氏".

Comment: @fefe: Ah, I just checked and instances of "摄氏零度" and "零摄氏度" appear to be roughly equal in Google.  I wonder if it's probably a regional preference.

Comment: @Claw Actually, by the national standard in China, you should not say "摄氏零度", though I have heard some people say it that way. "摄氏度" is one unit as a whole and should not be devided.

Comment: @Huang: Interesting; do you have a link online to these standards?

Comment: @Claw: Please see here:http://www.pep.com.cn/xiaoyu/jiaoshi/study/jszy/lhdw/bz/201012/t20101202_980870.htm   Section 4, term 26.

Answer (score 3):

We would say

> 最低气温 0 度左右

where the 'will be' is ignored. Furthermore,

> 0 度左右

becomes the predicate.